# " 'Title' is not a member of 'ASP.views ... " in ASP.NET MVC2 VB.NET Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm getting an odd compilation error in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using VB.NET:

> **Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message**: BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of 'ASP.views_ ...
>
> **Source:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" ...
```

Oddly, this error only happens when I host the site on IIS 5.1 (WinXP) and not on Cassini.  It also doesn't happen on every page.  It fails on the Index.aspx page referenced above, but succeeds on a dummy page I created call foo.aspx that uses the same `<% Page Title="" ...` syntax. In summary:

```
    File                 IIS 5.1             Cassini
    MyModel/Index.aspx   Fail                OK
    Home/Foo.aspx        OK                  OK
```

*EDIT: Now I'm getting it to fail in Cassini as well...odd*

I have two questions related to this problem:

1. Why am I getting this compilation error?
2. Is there a work-around so that I can avoid this error?

Comment: Whats the value of the **Inherits** attribute?

Comment: It's something like this: `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of MySolution.MVCReview.ValidationListViewModel))"`

Comment: Did you by any chance, change a class or file name in the project?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's the exact same code running in two different places.  It's a very odd issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Title="" statement. I have the feeling it will still fail on a different error.

Comment: If you haven't seen this take a look at this site - it might help: http://mattclingan.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/title-is-not-a-member-of-asp-what-the-hey/

Comment: @Julian thanks for the suggestions.  I did try removing the `Title=""` piece, but then it screams about `InvariantCulture...`.  It's a really odd thing.

Comment: I am assuming that this is a run-time error and not a compile-time error?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, that's correct.  I never did find a great answer to this question, but from some things I gleaned by "reading on the internet", it's a bug with VB.NET and MVC that causes run-time errors to be handled in an odd way.  So, instead of showing the actual error that occured, it shows a wierd error that seems like it shouldn't even exist.  I'm not sure if that's what happened, but I noticed that when I removed other runtime errors from my code, this magically went away.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem in a project I'm working on.  In my case it was because the 'Inherits' referred to a type which didn't exist.

Try browsing around the Object Explorer to make sure you've got your class name exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have lots of issues running MVC on IIS 5.1

The lack of support for wildcard filters is a bit of an issue with MVC routes.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the property pages of the deployment project. Under the Compilation tab, uncheck the option "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable". This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

the same happens when I host the site on IIS 7.
i had a renamed copy of the same form in the project,both inherits same name.
Then I deleted the old(renamed) form and now works fine.